# Rails PostgreSQL problems with order statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hi 
I changed my database from mySql to PostgreSQL and get an error every time I use query with :order statement

For example the following code works  perfectly in MySQL

```
Hour.sum("working_hours",:conditions=>['project_id=? AND reported_date=?',project,h.reported_date],:order=>"reported_date
```

But gives me an error in PostgreSQL

> PGError: ERROR:  column "hours.reported_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: ...rted_date='2010-10-06 00:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY reported_d..
>   : SELECT sum("hours".working_hours) AS sum_working_hours FROM "hours" WHERE (project_id=1 AND reported_date='2010-10-06 00:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY reported_date

If I delete the order statement then the query works ok
I will most appreciate any help on this subject

Answer (score 2):

PostreSQL is stricter to the SQL standard than MySQL is.

SQL states that if you `ORDER` by a column, that column must be `SELECT`ed and appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Try this:

```
Hour.sum("working_hours",:conditions=>['project_id=? AND reported_date=?',project,h.reported_date], :order=>"reported_date", :group_by => "working_hours"
```

Comment: This query actually returns an ordered hash of sums, grouped by reported_date.  If he wanted a sum of all working hours, this will not give him the correct answer.

Comment: PGError: ERROR:  column "hours.reported_date" must appear in the 
i tried it but i still get an error 
GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...:00:00.000000')  GROUP BY working_hours  ORDER BY reported_d...